# Change a different button when i click a button

Tags: android, xml, button

I am trying to create a memory game but I can't find any way to change a `x` button when I press a `y` button. Here is my code. 
I want to be able to handle different buttons when the private void `gridButtonClicked` is been used.

```
public class MainActivity2 extends ActionBarActivity {

private static final int NUM_ROWS =10 ;
private static final int NUM_COLS = 4;
Button buttons[][]=new Button[NUM_ROWS][NUM_COLS];


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity2);
    populateButtons();
}

private void populateButtons() {
    TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableForButtons);
    for(int row=0; row < NUM_ROWS; row++){
        TableRow tableRow=new TableRow(this);
        tableRow.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams( //we use this to fill the screen
                TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                1.0f));
        table.addView(tableRow);
        for(int col=0; col < NUM_COLS; col++){
           final int FINAL_COL=col;
            final int FINAL_ROW=row;
            Button button= new Button(this);
            button.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams( //we use this to fill the screen
                    TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    1.0f));
            button.setText("" + col + "," + row);   //text for every button
            button.setPadding(0,0,0,0);     //this is to make text visible even if the buttons are very small
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    gridButtonClicked(FINAL_COL,FINAL_ROW);   //we need final because we can't pass variables from inner classes
                }


            });
            tableRow.addView(button);
            buttons[row][col]=button;

        }
    }
}

        private void gridButtonClicked(int col, int row) {
            Toast.makeText(this,"clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Button button=buttons[row][col];
           // button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.abc_ab_share_pack_mtrl_alpha);
            String id= (String)  button.getText();

            if(id.equals("1,2")) {
                button.setText("" + col + "");  //change the button
            }
            if(id.equals("1")) {
                button.setText("" + col + "," + row);  //change the button
            }
            if(id.equals("2,1")) {
                button.setText("" + col + "");  //change the button
            }


        }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which button(s) do you want to change, and what do you want to change about it/them?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to create your own View (you can extends from a Button or ImageButton as well) and using an Adapter to fill up a GridView.

Afterwards you can control the behaviour or your View on its class.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for. It is just the same as interacting with the first button. Let me know if I misunderstood your question, or if you need more information!

```java
private void gridButtonClicked(int col, int row) {

            Toast.makeText(this,"clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Button button=buttons[row][col];

            int otherRow = ?;
            int otherColumn = ?;

            Button otherButton = buttons[otherRow,otherColumn];
            otherButton.setText("Whatever you want");

           // button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.abc_ab_share_pack_mtrl_alpha);
            String id= (String)  button.getText();

            if(id.equals("1,2")) {
                button.setText("" + col + "");  //change the button
            }
            if(id.equals("1")) {
                button.setText("" + col + "," + row);  //change the button
            }
            if(id.equals("2,1")) {
                button.setText("" + col + "");  //change the button
            }


        }
```